# CSHTML - using LINQ to sum values by a column for creating a table

Tags: c#, linq, razor, foreach

I am trying to sum values where that value has a specific MonthYear value in the list that I am using.

I am currently using the code below to perform this:

```
<table class="users">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach (var monthYear in Model.KeyIndicatorUseCount.Select(m => m.MonthYear).Distinct())
            {
                <th>@monthYear</th>
            }
        </tr>
        @foreach (var keyIndicator in Model.KeyIndicatorUseCount.OrderBy(f => f.Name).GroupBy(f => f.Name))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@keyIndicator.Key</td>
                @foreach (var monthYear in keyIndicator.OrderBy(f => f.MonthYear).GroupBy(f => f.MonthYear))
                {
                    <td>@(keyIndicator.Sum(f => f.Count))</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

At the moment the value that is shown in the cell for each MonthYear is the sum of all values in the table rather than the value for that specific MonthYear, the image below is what is currently being produced:

[image]

I have tried adding a Where clause to the sum but so far have been unable to get this to work without it producing an error.

How do I modify the code to get this to produce the required data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is correct but you should use a different variable.

This should be working:
    `@(monthYear.Sum(f => f.Count))`